# What kernel to use for Gaussian Process Regression on data with large flat region?

Tags: gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

The problem I'm working on has a region that's largely accurately modeled by a GP model using a squared exponential kernel. However, there is a large region in the "truth" model that is uniformly zero, with all samples taken from this region being zero as well. However, the GP model in this region oscillates from positive to negative when it's necessary for the problem I'm working on that this region is accurately modeled as uniformly zero, or at least negative when the remainder of the data is positive. Adding a dot product kernel to the squared exponential kernel to create a custom kernel helps somewhat but can't eliminate the spurious oscillations.

Comment: you will want a kernel which is *nonstationary*: an example being the dot-prod kernel you tried. Unfortunately, these are relatively nonstandard. You may have luck with a deep gaussian process (https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.02904), or with a hurdle GP (https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2022/05/09/hurdle-lognormal-gaussian-brms/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out

Answer (score 3):

You can try to build a more complex kernel function, which suites your prior knowledge better. When you have an flat region that is open to one side, you could use a changepoint kernel to encode this information. For a flat region that is in between two non-flat ones, this becomes more complex, but is also doable.

When you want to read up on it, I can recommend the following dissertation of Duvenaud [here](https://doi.org/10.17863/CAM.14087) (page 20).